# Python PYODBC executing T-SQL function

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I am trying to execute a T-SQL function custom function which returns data, the code runs without error but when I try to print the result it prints only some rows, the function works well on SQL Server.

This is the code:

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password, timeout=0)

CompanyList = pd.read_csv('List.csv')

for i in range(1):    
    cursor.execute("select * from MA_PROC('"+CompanyList.iloc[i][0]+"')") 
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    while rows:
        print(rows)
        if cursor.nextset():
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
        else:
            rows = None
```

Can anyone let me know why the code is not returning all the rows from the function?

Comment: no..i am asking why the cursor is not able to print all the rows, the function has only one resultset..and if i retrieve the data directly from table it shows all the rows..

Comment: `fetchall()` already retrieves all of the rows in the cursor. You need to iterate over the rows collection, e.g.: [the fetchall() example](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#fetchall).